# using Viewstate for ListItemCollection in WebUserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a UserControl which uses a ListItemCollection member. 
I can add Items to this ListItemCollection, but It is cleared after a postback. 
How can I use a viewstate with it.

```
    public partial class IgList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public ListItemCollection Items = new ListItemCollection();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Items = new ListItemCollection();
            }
        }

        public void fillList()
        {
            int i = 1; 

            foreach (ListItem li in Items)
            {
                LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                lb.ID = "IgListItem" + i; 
                lb.Style.Add("clear", "both");
                lb.Style.Add("display", "block");
                lb.Style.Add("width", "100%");
                lb.Style.Add("height", "23px");
                lb.Font.Underline = false; 
                lb.ForeColor=  System.Drawing.Color.Black; 
                lb.Height= Unit.Pixel(23); 
                lb.BorderColor= System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;  
                lb.BorderStyle= BorderStyle.Solid;
                lb.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);
                lb.Text = li.Text;
                lb.CommandArgument = li.Value;
                lb.CommandName = "ItemSelected"; 
                i++;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where on your main page is fillList() being called?

Answer (score 1):

Take `Items = new ListItemCollection();` out of `!Page.IsPostBack` having it in there will only put data in `Items` on the first page load.  If you really want to use a view state you can, you can set it on initial page load, where you are now, and set the control out side of that block, wither way will accomplish the same thing.  I prefer the first method in case the data has changed since the last ViewState was set.

Comment: It wont persist items even if I add or remove Page_Load codes.

Comment: Correct, you have to load the items on postback, the way you have it written the items list is blank.  You can do this by using the PreInit().  If you need to persist the items, always and they don't change, you can add them in the design. Can you show the updated code that isn't working please?

Comment: Its a user control and items are added by a web page.

Comment: That is well understood.  Have you tried any of my suggestions? Do you understand why the items are not being persisted?